# HTML UL Navigation Breaks in Newsletter?

Tags: html, css

Code is seemingly alright when viewing it with the source html/css files, but when is sent through "Webtools Toolbox", (a portal that manages Email+ and Skin Designs that utilizes HTML/CSS), the UL Menu breaks in the email. Is there a way to make the UL width scale to whatever parameter of the email content? You can view the source here: https://illinois.edu/skinDesigner/preview/10087

```
<tr>
<td>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="#">
<tr>
<td style="border: medium none;
font-size: 12px;
padding-bottom: 15px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;">
<ul style="list-style:none">

<li class="listle" ><a class="arttle"   
href="http://promisemagazine.org/category/longform/">LONGFORM</a> |</li>

<li class="listle" ><a class="arttle"  
href="http://promisemagazine.org/category/alumni/">ALUMNI</a> |</li>

<li class="listle" ><a class="arttle" 
href="http://promisemagazine.org/category/community/">COMMUNITY</a> |</li>

<li class="listle" ><a class="arttle" 
href="http://promisemagazine.org/category/giving/">GIVING</a> |</li>

<li class="listle" ><a class="arttle" 
href="http://promisemagazine.org/category/opinion/">OPINION</a> |</li>

<li class="listle" ><a class="arttle" 
href="http://promisemagazine.org/category/research/">RESEARCH</a>|</li>

<li class="listle" ><a class="arttle" 
href="http://promisemagazine.org/category/schools/">SCHOOLS</a></li>
</ul>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
/td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set class names on your elements, but there is no CSS. Email providers strip `<head>` and `<body>` tags from your document, so whatever you specified in there is lost.

Try to use `<span>` instead of `li` for you menu, or use a `table` for the menu. Table will take 100% of available width.

EDIT:

Another option is to simply show links:

```
<td style="border: medium none;
font-size: 12px;
padding-bottom: 15px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;">

<a href="http://promisemagazine.org/category/longform/">LONGFORM</a> |
<a href="http://promisemagazine.org/category/alumni/">ALUMNI</a> |
<a href="http://promisemagazine.org/category/community/">COMMUNITY</a> |
<a href="http://promisemagazine.org/category/giving/">GIVING</a> |
<a href="http://promisemagazine.org/category/opinion/">OPINION</a> |
<a href="http://promisemagazine.org/category/research/">RESEARCH</a>|
<a href="http://promisemagazine.org/category/schools/">SCHOOLS</a>
</td>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm not familiar with <span> (a newbie hobbyist), so I'm looking up this function at the moment.

Comment: Thanks Andrei. I shall have to update my knowledge on span menus as well for the future, but this simple solution really saved my back. Works well, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure I understand the problem (are you worried about people changing the size of their email window, or if the content does not fit the table?)

Assuming you are trying to keep content within square window, try putting it in a `div`, and then adjusting the width of the div to fit your table, and displaying `inline block`. I added margin: 0 auto to center content like your format above.

Code example:

```
<div style="width: x; height: y; display: inline-block; margin: 0 auto">

    <ul style="list-style:none">

       <li>
       <li>
       <li>
       <li>

    </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: The menu formatting breaks in the email as shown: http://imgur.com/0Rb3bmp - the div tag didn't fix it.

Comment: sorry - completely misunderstood. I agree with Andrei looks like issue with class not being interpreted by email because no CSS file can apply

Answer (score 0):

I would stick with only tables for HTML email. The source code looks horrible but that's your only option.